# Quote Trigger Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Boolean at line 32 column 89

Tags: trigger, opportunity, sobject, quote, boolean

I can't seem to figure my issue here on the code below. Originally I had Opportunity__c and was getting a invalid field error. I replaced Opportunity__c with the OpportunityId field and received the following error.
 **Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Boolean at line 32 column 89** Any help with this error would be greatly appreciated

```
trigger MarkPrimaryQuote on Quote (before insert, before update) {
    List<Quote> quoteListToUpdate = new List<Quote>();

    Set<Id> opppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Quote qRec : Trigger.new){
        if(qRec.OpportunityId!= null){
            opppIds.add(qRec.OpportunityId);
        }
    }
    Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOfOpps = new Map<Id,Opportunity>([Select id,(Select Primary_Quote__c from Quotes) from Opportunity where Id IN :opppIds]);
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(Quote qRec : Trigger.new){
            qRec.Primary_Quote__c = true;
        }
        for(Opportunity opp : mapOfOpps.values()){
            for(Quote existingQuote : opp.Quotes){
                existingQuote.Primary_Quote__c =false;
                quoteListToUpdate.add(existingQuote);
            }
        }
        if(quoteListToUpdate.size() > 0){
            update quoteListToUpdate;
        }
    }
    else if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Quote qRec : Trigger.new){
            Quote oldQuote = trigger.oldMap.get(qRec.id);
            if(oldQuote.Oracle_Quote__c != qRec.Oracle_Quote__c){
                qRec.Primary_Quote__c =false;

                if(qRec.OpportunityId!= null && mapOfOpps.containsKey(qRec.OpportunityId)){
                    for(Quote existingQuote : mapOfOpps.containsKey(qRec.OpportunityId).Quotes){
                        if(existingQuote.id != qRec.id){
                            quoteListToUpdate.add(existingQuote);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(quoteListToUpdate.size() > 0){
            update quoteListToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The map function `containsKey` returns a boolean value. But you try to get the Quotes out of it.

You should use `get` function of map. Change this

```
for(Quote existingQuote : mapOfOpps.containsKey(qRec.OpportunityId).Quotes){
```

to

```
for(Quote existingQuote : mapOfOpps.get(qRec.OpportunityId).Quotes){
```

Hope it helps.